# Help with integral $\int x^3\sqrt {1+4x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

Id like to know how to solve the following integral

$\int x^3\sqrt {1+4x^2}dx$

I tried substituting $t=x^2$ but I dont know what to do from here.

Comment: Instead, try the substitution $1+4x^2=u$.

Comment: Where does this substitution come from?

Comment: What are the limits of the integral?

Comment: Its the antiderivative.

Comment: I would like to see $u=1+4x^2$ worked out I think it runs into trouble.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Nope, it's the most natural substitution to get rid of the complicated term inside the root.

Comment: It works ! nice.

Comment: Although you already have the concrete answer, I'd like to comment something. Usually when you have a polynomial with a constant, try to include the constant every time. you basically kill one term out of the problem. This doesn't always work, but I believe that you'll find this useful in the next couple of problems of the same level of difficulty.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: let $\color{red}{t=1+4x^2} \implies \frac{dt}{dx}=8x \iff \color{green}{xdx=\frac{1}{8}dt}$.

Then the integral becomes $$\begin{align}\int x^2 \sqrt{\color{red}{1+4x^2}} \color{green}{xdx} & =\color{green}{\frac{1}{8}}\int \color{purple}{x^2} \sqrt{\color{red}{t}} \color{green}{dt}\\ &={\frac{1}{8}}\int \color{purple}{\frac{t-1}{4}} \sqrt{t} dt \\
&=\frac{1}{32}\int(t-1)t^{1/2}dt\\&=\frac{1}{32}\int(t^{3/2}-t^{1/2})dt. \end{align}$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: That's actually pretty sick, I'm not going to lie.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int x^{3}\root{1 + 4x^{2}}\,\dd x}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int x^{3}\root{1 + 4x^{2}}\,\dd x}
> =\half\
> \overbrace{\int x^{2}\root{1 + 4x^{2}}\,\dd\pars{x^{2}}}^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ x^{2} \equiv t\ \imp\ x = t^{1/2}}}\ =\
> \half\int t\root{1 + 4t}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 8}\int\bracks{\pars{1 + 4t}^{3/2} - \pars{1 + 4t}^{1/2}}\,\dd t
> ={1 \over 8}\bracks{%
> {1 \over 10}\pars{1 + 4t}^{5/2} - {1 \over 6}\pars{1 + 4t}^{3/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large%
> {1 \over 240}\bracks{3\pars{1 + 4x^{2}}^{5/2} - 5\pars{1 + 4x^{2}}^{3/2}}}
> + \mbox{a constant}
> \end{align}